# Failed Web upgrade of Ubuntu from 13.10 to 14.04, what now?

Tags: 13.10, 14.04

Tried to upgrade via a Ubuntu upgrade download from 13.10 to 14.04 and all seemed well.
All the files downloaded, but the machine hung on one of the printer packages - I waited one hour - forcing a reboot.
Now I have a desktop which is pretty well organized as before, but no mouse no internet access and no network.
Ubuntu boots with a heap of errors and will also not shut down.
What is the procedure to either undo the install and return me to my previous version,
or to get the screwed install to correct itself?
It would be a pity if I lost all my work such as installed programs, links etc.
I am a beginner and would not have the foggiest where to start. 
I have downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04 ISO and burned the DVD.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot from the DVD.
2. Mount the hard disk.
3. Open a terminal.
4. Assuming the disk becomes mounted to, e.g. `/media/disk` (it will be something different; change as appropriate), run `chroot /media/disk`.
5. Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.
6. Run `sudo apt-get -f install`.

That might fix it.  If not, you might need to finish installing some packages from the DVD, in which case:

1. Run `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Now you need to add the DVD to this sources list.  I don't have a 14.04 disc handy, so you'll need to edit it appropriately yourself.  The line to add will look basically like this:
   `deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 _Trusty Tahr_ - Release i386 (2014...something)]/ trusty main restricted`
3. Run `sudo apt-get update`.
4. Run `sudo apt-get -f install`.
5. Run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Doing all of that will probably fix it.

If it doesn't, you can always save your `/home/username` directory by renaming it to something else, then delete everything else on the hard disk (obviously, don't `rm -rf /home` if that's where you left your renamed homedir), and then install from the DVD again.  Then you can either rename your home directory back to what it was and login again, or copy the files you need out of it.  Depending on how many files you want to save, you might opt to be extra careful and copy the files to external media before reinstalling.